# Are reads and writes for uint8 in golang atomic?

Tags: go, atomic, uint

As in the title, are read and write operations regarding  uint8, atomic?
Logically it must be a single cpu instruction obviously to read and write for a 8 bit variable. But in any case, two cores could simultaneously read and write from the memory, is it possible to create a stale data this way?

Comment: obligatory: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong

Comment: Does the OP worry that 8 bits might not be sent to or from RAM or a cache line or a core register coherently?  Or that data, once read, could be stale because of another core's write?  The last sentence asks about stale data, and yes, data can become stale in one core, or in one goroutine, if another goroutine has logic to write to that 8 bit location.  Gophers prefer to use coroutines and channels.  If you haven't seen the recommendation "Do not communicate by sharing memory; instead, share memory by communicating", please see https://blog.golang.org/share-memory-by-communicating.

Comment: @WeakPointer I saw it. I have read all the documentation. In my case, I am required to use locks, however I preferred to  avoid it by atomic variables for cleaner code. So, this said 8 bit data, could it be stale even if there was 1 core?

Comment: @OzumSafa: it depends on what you mean by "stale". If you want visibility between goroutines, there's no guarantees unless you create a ["happens before"](https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_2) relationship between writing and reading the value. Atomic operations guarantee that the value is read and written in its entirety into memory, but only locks and channels can create a "happens before" ordering to ensure the reads and writes between goroutines are synchronized.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no guarantee that the access on native types are on any platform atomic. This is why there is [`sync/atomic`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/). See also [the advice in the memory model documentation](https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_1).

Example for generic way of atomically setting a value ([Play](http://play.golang.org/p/kF8IdH5Iok))

```
var ax atomic.Value // may be globally accessible

x := uint8(5)

// set atomically
ax.Store(x)

x = ax.Load().(uint8)
```

Probably more efficient solution for `uint8` ([Play](http://play.golang.org/p/I3m_kl45lE)):

```
var ax int64 // may be globally accessible

x := uint8(5)

atomic.StoreInt64(&ax, 10)

x = uint8(atomic.LoadInt64(&ax))

fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", x, x)
```

Comment: Oh sweet, I was clever :). Thanks for the answer I did not realize I could use atomic.Value, and predefined methods did not work for me.

Comment: Although, do you know if this atomic.Value is simply a lock system underneath? Because being able to make any data type atomic does not seem possible in cpu level :)

Comment: @OzumSafa: You can load and store anything "atomically"(indirectly) by using a pointer. `atomic.Value` is a little more complex in that it uses the 2 words for the `interface{}`, but it's the same concept.

Comment: @JimB I shall look into the source then :) Thanks JimB

Comment: `each read of a single-word-sized or sub-word-sized memory location must observe a value actually written to that location (perhaps by a concurrent executing goroutine) and not yet overwritten` uint8 is sub-word-size, which means it's atomic in the end?

Comment: Another way of asking the same question I made in a previous comment is: How can you demonstrate that writing/reading uint8 is not atomic?

Comment: You could do concurrent reads and writes and see if you observe intermittent values. But this is besides the point, if you want to have atomic values  that work cross-platform and are not susceptible to the intricacies of your runtime platform you use the `atomic` package.

Comment: `You could do concurrent reads and writes and see if you observe intermittent values` So if I get two goroutines to write `1` and `2` to a `uint8` and then read back without using `atomic` you would expect I can observe anything that is not `1` or `2`?

Comment: For x86 (and probably most ISAs) writing single bytes can be done without tearing AFAIR so that specific behavior shouldn't occur for uint8 but that's only for write operations. If you want to do a compare and swap that would be more than one operation and susceptible to interference from concurrent processes (i.e. out of order execution, caching, etc.).

Answer (score 10):

No. If you want atomic operations, you can use the [`sync/atomic`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/) package.

If you mean "would 8bit operations be atomic even if I ignore the Go [memory model](https://golang.org/ref/mem)?", then the answer is still, <strike>it depends</strike> probably not.

If the hardware guarantees atomicity of read/write operations, then it might be atomic. But that still doesn't guarantee cache coherence, or compiler optimizations from reordering operations. You need to serialize the operations somehow, with the primitives Go provides in the "atomic" package, and using the "sync" package and channels to coordinate between goroutines.