# Golang: what is atomic read used for?

Tags: go

Here we have a go case provided by `Go by Example`, to explain the atomic package.

https://gobyexample.com/atomic-counters

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"
import "sync/atomic"

func main() {

    var ops uint64

    for i := 0; i < 50; i++ {
        go func() {
            for {
                atomic.AddUint64(&ops, 1)

                time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
            }
        }()
    }

    time.Sleep(time.Second)

    opsFinal := atomic.LoadUint64(&ops) // Can I replace it?
    fmt.Println("ops:", opsFinal)
}
```

For `atomic.AddUnit64`, it's straightforward to understand.

### Question1

Regarding `read` operation, why is it necessary to use `atomic.LoadUnit`, rather than read this counter directly?

### Question2

Can I replace the last two lines with the following lines?

**Before**

```
    opsFinal := atomic.LoadUint64(&ops) // Can I replace it?
    fmt.Println("ops:", opsFinal)
```

**After**

```
    opsFinal := ops
    fmt.Println("ops:", opsFinal)
```

### Question3

Are we worrying about this scenario?

1. CPU loads the data from memory
2. CPU manipulates data
3. Write data back to memory. Even though this step is fast, but it still takes time.

When CPU doing step3, another goroutine may read incomplete and dirty data from memory. So use `atomic.LoadUint64` could avoid this kind of problem?

### Reference

[Are reads and writes for uint8 in golang atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133364/are-reads-and-writes-for-uint8-in-golang-atomic)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's necessary to use `atomic.LoadUint64` because there's no guarantee that the `:=` operator does an atomic read.

For an example, consider a theoretical case where `atomic.AddUint64` is implemented as follows:

1. Take a lock.
2. Read the lower 32 bits.
3. Read the upper 32 bits.
4. Add the number to the lower 32 bits.
5. Add carry-out of the first operation to the upper 32 bits.
6. Write the lower 32 bits.
7. Write the upper 32 bits.
8. Release lock.

If you do not use `atomic.LoadUint64`, you could be reading an intermediary result between step 6 and 7.

On certain platforms (e.g. older ARM processors without native support for 64 bit integer operations), it may very well be implemented in the way described above.

The same applies for other sized integers/pointers as well. The exact behaviour will depend on the implementation of the `atomic` package and the CPU/memory architecture that the program is running on.

Comment: Atomics doesn't take locks wth. Atomics implemented thru processor instructions.
here is how atomic implemented in golang

```asm
TEXT ·AddUint64(SB),NOSPLIT,$0
 JMP runtime∕internal∕atomic·Xadd64(SB)
```

```asm
// uint64 Xadd64(uint64 volatile *val, int64 delta)
// Atomically:
// *val += delta;
// return *val;
TEXT ·Xadd64(SB), NOSPLIT, $0-24
 MOVQ ptr+0(FP), BX
 MOVQ delta+8(FP), AX
 MOVQ AX, CX
 LOCK
 XADDQ AX, 0(BX)
 ADDQ CX, AX
 MOVQ AX, ret+16(FP)
 RET
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if the processor's 64 bit load and store are single instructions, you still need `atomic`.

Consider the writing goroutine is running in cpu1 and the reading gorouting in cpu2. Writing to the variable would first write to the cpu1's cache and it may not put it in the main memory unless the cache space is needed for something else. cpu2 would not see the write at all when it fetches from main memory.

By calling the atomic functions, the data is explicitly written to the main memory and loaded from main memory.

Answer (score 0):

according to golang memory model:

1. every read will act like it really do a memory load(wont be optimized to a const val after first load, like in c++ O3?).
2. in 64-bit arch, memory load/write will operate at 64-bit once, so two 32bit in a uint64 will always be observed/write at the same time like atomic
3. compiler might reorder read/write if it did not change the behavior in one goroutine. means read/write of different value might happens in different order in different goroutine.

so, yes, your code's replace is correct, you can do that.